# How to get variant metafield value + price combined in shopify collection page's each product

Tags: shopify, metadata, product-variations

This is the product page. I have here "variant meta field value" + "variant price" combined. So, when I select a variant, it shows variant price + (related) variant meta field value. As you can see on the right side.

[image]

How I can do the same for other pages, where we have a list of products. ex: single collection pages etc. Anyone did/do similar things?

[image]

My Aim is to get: Product variant Metafield value + Variant price combined. So, when I select variant from dropdown, I'll get both of them and can show below the product title.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your image of code into a code block? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: You want to do display the metafield value and the price on each product card of a collection ? You can use the same code inside a loop through the collection's products. You'll need to modify your product card liquid template.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a point to this exercise? When you go to checkout, your customer will only ever pay the variant price, never the combined price with the metafield. So what is the point of the metafield price? Seems like a lot of work for no benefit.

Comment: Actually, we want to show the variant meta fields with the product price. The meta fields will have some important info, which is related to variation and we want to show it to the visitor. That's the matter.

Are you sure it's a lot of work needed? I am not sure. If it's almost impossible for me I should not waste my time. But as you can see we get it done already on single product page. So why not on collection product page? Thanks

Comment: If you examine the code making up the option value, you can see there where to combine the values if you want. You're that one that already renders them separate, so now, just add them together.

Comment: It's the product page It's works for single product. But, when it’s a list of product,  it always return one product value. Others not work. How i can achieve this same things on attached image for a collection list products? Please help, i think you are very experienced.